# How to match right single quotation mark character in an Apache RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the following URL:

```
http://olddomain.com/macmillan’s-st-luke-passion
```

Which contains the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK character (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)

To redirect to a new location. However, I cannot get Apache to do this.

For reference my redirect code (in a VirtualHost) is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^macmillan\xE2\x80\x99s-st-luke-passion$ http://newdomain.com/tickets/events/macmillans-st-luke-passion [R=301,L]
```

The file has other redirects for exact matching URLs, and one catch all redirect at the bottom of the page. This one is intended to match any remaining URLs to `/events/(old url)`. For example, it will send `olddomain.com/page-title` to `newdomain.com/events/page-title`.

```
Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.com/events/
```

What's happening at present is Apache is ignoring the specific rule which contains the `\x` encoded string for the right quote character `’`.

And falls through to the fallback redirect that sends the URL to the wrong place.

Can anyone help with how to match a URL with a right quote character `’` in an Apache `RewriteRule` (or `RedirectMatch`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in virtual host config file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?macmillan\xE2\x80\x99s-st-luke-passion$ http://newdomain.com/tickets/events/macmillans-st-luke-passion [NC,R=301,L]
```

Leading slash is required while matching in Apache or vhost config but not when used in htaccess. Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Adding the / at the start of the regex pattern worked fine thanks. Forgot about the / rules!